# How to clear EditText error state on orientation change

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to clear error for EditText, when orientation screen change. I try in onStart() method set setError(null), but it doesn't work.

I tried it on the new project, but doesn't still work. Whem i click on button, field set error, when i change orientation i expect, that erro clear, but it doen't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText text;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            text.setError("Error");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    text.setError(null);
}
```

}

Comment: No, it doesn't work...I also tried it on the new project.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:

It seems you have to clear errors onPause instead of onResume/onStart:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        text.setError(null);
    }
```

The above works for me.

**OLD**:

Android will automatically handle EditText for you, and its states, on orientation change.

If you want to handle the state yourself you need to implement and override **onSaveInstanceState** and not call super(). You don't need to override onRestoreInstanceState unless you need to handle restoring for other stuff.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: but I need to save text state of EditText, if I don't call super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); the text of EditText won't be save automatically, i must do it by my self. Have other way to handle error state of EditText? The problem is, that i don't know, when editText takes reference to the error message after restore, cause in onStart() and in onResume() EditText has null reference to the error message, however in that time text message of EditTExt has his reference to the String object.

Comment: yes, I know that is work) But in my case I've condition, if the activity killed force, i save field state and, when user open app again the field (text and error) mustn't clear.But if user go to the other activity or exit from app by himself, when he return the field state must clear. So for this reasean i can't clear error state in onPause(), cause field state will be clear every time when the another activity comes foreground.

Comment: Then it seems to me that the best solution would be to handle saving the text yourself in onSaveInstanceState AND you should have said so from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do when **orientation** changes.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            // Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                text.setError(null);

            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                text.setText("Something");
            }
          }
```

And you can just the value of TextView as text.setText("") if you want to clear the "Error message" and if again the orientation changes, just set the text to anything you want.

Comment: thanks, but I need  every time save text from EditText and than after the screen  rotation put text to the EditText. I think must be the easier way)

Comment: You mean to say that everytime when the screen rotates, you don't want the value of textview to be changed ?

Comment: I am sorry..I am still not getting your point here because you don't want the value to change but still want to clear the error message.